# Grails 3.0.10 GORM inheritance

Tags: grails, inheritance, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I created a new web-api profile project in Grails 3.0.10 and tried to set up a simple domain class hierarchy like this...

**//This is in testapi/src/main/groovy**

```
package test.api.common
class DomainObject {

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
}
```

**This is in testate/grails-app/domain**

```
package test.api
import test.common.DomainObject

class Organization extends DomainObject {

    String col1
    String col2

    static constraints = {
        col1 maxSize:35
        col2 maxSize:6
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}

class Org1 extends Organization {

    String col3
}
```

When i try to run this getting the below exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.datastore.gorm.config.GrailsDomainClassMappingContext]:  Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:267)
... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.config.GrailsDomainClassPersistentEntity.getRootEntity(GrailsDomainClassPersistentEntity.java:203)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.AbstractMappingContext.initializePersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:259)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntities(AbstractMappingContext.java:183)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.config.GrailsDomainClassMappingContext.<init>(GrailsDomainClassMappingContext.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
```

If i remove the "extends Organization" from class Acquirer everything works fine.

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It think your problem is that `DomainObject` is not a domain class. You *could* make it a domain class, but I suspect a trait will be a better fit for your case.

```
package test.api.common
trait DomainObject {

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
}

package test.api
import test.common.DomainObject

class Organization implements DomainObject {

    String col1
    String col2

    static constraints = {
        col1 maxSize:35
        col2 maxSize:6
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @EmmanuelRosa It worked. But I am not able to understand the issue with `class DomainObject' as it works with `class Organization extends DomainObject`. The moment any other class inherits `Organization` it starts failing. Any view on this?

Comment: I find it strange that it works only with the organization class because it's my understanding that all classes involved in domain class instance (except for Object) must be domain classes.